# During installing MySQL, error about Failed to start MySQL Community Server

Tags: mysql, database, debian

System: Debina 10
Error Message

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-07-07 21:48:31 UTC; 14ms ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 1453 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1488 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1488 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Server startup in progress"
```

[image]

This happened during installition, not running.

Comment: please show the mysql error log, with the oart that show s the exact error

Comment: MySQL is not installed. This is the error during installing.

Comment: your error message comes from the mysql service so something was installed and added the neccesary, so look for the error log

Comment: `journalctl -u mysql.service -n 50`

Comment: -- Logs begin at Tue 2020-07-07 23:57:28 UTC, end at Wed 2020-07-08 01:51:01 UTC. -- 
-- No entries --